# SwiftUI passing selected date from modal to parent variables

Tags: swiftui

Need help with this please.

I have a view with 2 date variables and I want to show a modal which have the datepicker and let user pick different dates for these variables.

Currently I have two buttons that show the same sheet but pass different variable to the modal.
The problem the variable don’t update after dismissing the modal.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var secOneDate = Date()
    @State private var secTwoDate = Date()
    @State private var isDatepickerPresented = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack{
                Button{
                    isDatepickerPresented = true
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "calendar")
                        .imageScale(.large)
                        .foregroundColor(.indigo)
                        
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: $isDatepickerPresented){
                    DatePickView(selectDate: $secOneDate)
                }
                
                Text("SecOneDate: \(secOneDate.formatted(date: .abbreviated, time: .shortened))") 
            }
            .padding()
            
            HStack{
                Button{
                    isDatepickerPresented = true
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "calendar")
                        .imageScale(.large)
                        .foregroundColor(.mint)
                    
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: $isDatepickerPresented)
                { 
                    DatePickView(selectDate: $secTwoDate)
                }
                Text("SecTwoDate: \(secTwoDate.formatted(date: .abbreviated, time: .shortened))") 
            }
            .padding()
            
        }
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

struct DatePickView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    @Binding var selectDate: Date
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 20) {
            HStack {
                Text("\(selectDate)")
                    .padding()
                
                Spacer()
                Button {
                    dismiss()
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "delete.backward.fill")
                        .foregroundColor(.indigo)
                }
                
            }.padding()
            
            
            DatePicker("", selection: $selectDate)
                .datePickerStyle(.graphical)
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In `DatePickView` change `@State var selectDate = Date()` to `@Binding var selectDate: Date`

Comment: Unrelated but you should present the sheet by item rather than by a `Bool`. In your design always the **first** sheet is presented

Comment: Don't use `@State` in the `App` struct: use them in the `ContentView` and then `@Binding` in the `DatePickView`. You don't use those dates anyhow in `MyApp`, `@State` is supposed to be used in a `View`.

Comment: @Yrb did that initially but only the first date changes, when the other date is selected and the sheet ispresented the second date doesn’t update, its allways the first one, in the example above secOneDate is always updated no matter which button presents the sheet.

Comment: @HunterLion thank you for reply. originally I did what you mentioned, but only secOneDate is updated no matter which button presents the sheet, what I need to do is let the user select different date and time using one datepicker sheet by passing the variable to be changed to the datepicker, yet with the edited code only secOneDate gets updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, thank you for your minimal, reproducible example: it is clear and can be immediately used for debugging. Answering to your question:

The problem with your code is that you have only one variable that opens the sheet for both dates. Even though you are correctly passing the two different `@Binding`s, when you toggle `isDatepickerPresented` you are asking SwiftUI to show *both* sheets, but this will never happen. Without knowing, you are always triggering the *first* of the sheet presentations - the one that binds `secOneDate`. The sheet that binds `secTwoDate` is never shown because you can't have two sheets simultaneously.

With that understanding, the solution is simple: use two different trigger variables. Here's the code corrected (`DatePickView` doesn't change):

```
struct Example: View {
    
    @State private var secOneDate = Date()
    @State private var secTwoDate = Date()
    @State private var isDatepickerOnePresented = false
    @State private var isDatepickerTwoPresented = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack{
                Button{
                    isDatepickerOnePresented = true
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "calendar")
                        .imageScale(.large)
                        .foregroundColor(.indigo)
                        
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: $isDatepickerOnePresented){
                    DatePickView(selectDate: $secOneDate)
                }
                
                Text("SecOneDate: \(secOneDate.formatted(date: .abbreviated, time: .shortened))")
            }
            .padding()
            
            HStack{
                Button{
                    isDatepickerTwoPresented = true
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "calendar")
                        .imageScale(.large)
                        .foregroundColor(.mint)
                    
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: $isDatepickerTwoPresented) {
                    DatePickView(selectDate: $secTwoDate)
                }
                Text("SecTwoDate: \(secTwoDate.formatted(date: .abbreviated, time: .shortened))")
            }
            .padding()
            
        }
    }
}
```